# On saving html files in visual stuido lines got messed up

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have developed an angular application using VS code.On saving html file, the lines got messed up. It automatically re-aligns. I don't know what is causing this. This issue suddenly showed up. Can someone help me to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for programming community only. For tools related things you have to use different stack overflow community.You have to switch off auto save on save. So then only it won't reset. For VS code I found https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cbrevik.toggle-format-on-save